# Problem with BeanUtils from Apache

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm trying to set a property in a bean and I cant seem to get BeanUtils to work...

Heres a small example of the problem I am getting.

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.run();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Bean bean = new Bean();
            BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, "name", "myName");
            System.out.println(bean.getName());
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private class Bean
    {
        private String name;

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get an InvocationTargetException, saying "Cannot set name"  Also when I the property string to "Name", I don't get the error, BUT the name isn't set.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take the private attribute off of the Bean class. As BeanUtils is using reflection, it can't get access to the method 'setName'. The reason why you can access a private inner class normally, is that the java compiler does special tricks to allow you access. But since BeanUtils isn't using those tricks, it can't.

Comment: Making the Bean class its own upper level class should make it work, right?

Comment: As long as it's public, or package protected and in the same package as the Example class, yes.

Comment: No that didn't work, I Had the bean class public and in its own java file earlier...  I only made it private when I was making a shortened version of my problem for posting here, as opposed to posting loads of unwanted code.

Comment: i changed the Bean class to public and did java -classpath .:commons-beanutils.jar:commons-logging.jar Example  and it worked.